# Mutable index? Python Pandas Dataframe ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple duplicate values as the index, for example:
[image]

I need to split the values 350 contains this into 351,352,353 and so on...
I want to change the values of the index to give them a unique value to operate uniquely on them. I tried changing the index and I got this error:
[image]

The purpose of my code is to reindex and get the values of only what is in my list.
What's the best way to go about this? Is there a way to change the index values so I can work on the data frame?

```
my_finallist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
data_backup.reindex(my_finallist)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-2af1a8aae353> in <module>
----> 1 data_backup.reindex(my_finallist)

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    310         @wraps(func)
    311         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Callable[..., Any]:
--> 312             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    313 
    314         kind = inspect.Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4171         kwargs.pop("axis", None)
   4172         kwargs.pop("labels", None)
-> 4173         return super().reindex(**kwargs)
   4174 
   4175     def drop(

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   4806 
   4807         # perform the reindex on the axes
-> 4808         return self._reindex_axes(
   4809             axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy
   4810         ).__finalize__(self, method="reindex")

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy)
   4017         index = axes["index"]
   4018         if index is not None:
-> 4019             frame = frame._reindex_index(
   4020                 index, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance
   4021             )

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _reindex_index(self, new_index, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance)
   4036             new_index, method=method, level=level, limit=limit, tolerance=tolerance
   4037         )
-> 4038         return self._reindex_with_indexers(
   4039             {0: [new_index, indexer]},
   4040             copy=copy,

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _reindex_with_indexers(self, reindexers, fill_value, copy, allow_dups)
   4872 
   4873             # TODO: speed up on homogeneous DataFrame objects
-> 4874             new_data = new_data.reindex_indexer(
   4875                 index,
   4876                 indexer,

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in reindex_indexer(self, new_axis, indexer, axis, fill_value, allow_dups, copy, consolidate, only_slice)
   1299         # some axes don't allow reindexing with dups
   1300         if not allow_dups:
-> 1301             self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)
   1302 
   1303         if axis >= self.ndim:

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _can_reindex(self, indexer)
   3474         # trying to reindex on an axis with duplicates
   3475         if not self._index_as_unique and len(indexer):
-> 3476             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
   3477 
   3478     def reindex(self, target, method=None, level=None, limit=None, tolerance=None):

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Comment: so, the index label is 833 or the position is 833?

Comment: index label is 833. I need to split all the values that 833 holds into 834, 835, 836 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Use `rename` working nice also with duplicated index values:

```
df = df.rename(index={833:778})
#index is default value, so possible use
#df = df.rename({833:778})
```

If need counter for index values (but possible created new duplicates):

```
df.index += df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()

#working like
#df.index = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + df.index
```

Comment: I need to split all the values that 833 holds into 834, 835, 836 and so on...

Comment: @HariPrasadRangaraj - hmmm, can you explain more? What is logic here? In datasets are not `834, 835, ...` ? If rename `833` with some logic to `834, 835, 836...` then output is not possible duplicates `834` or `835` or `836` and same logic for another values?

Comment: So lets say index 830 holds 5 values, I need to split all the 5 values into different indexes, like 831,832,833 , refer to my first image

Comment: @HariPrasadRangaraj - So working `df.index  = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + df.index` ?

Comment: That didn't work. There are still duplicates that exist...

Comment: @HariPrasadRangaraj - yes, I know. Is not possible use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` for default index like `0,1,2,3...` ?